# Which apache or PHP module is responsible to get posted variable assigned to same name after form submit

Tags: php, forms, post

Is any module or extension responsible for getting the form post value in the same name without assigning in apache/php server?

To explain more:

I have a form like

```
<label for='usernameid'>Username:</label> 
<input type='text' name='username' id='usernameid' tabindex='1' maxlength='45'/>

<label for='password'>Password:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' tabindex='2' maxlength='45'/>
```

After submitting this form, in the next php page
They are checking the value directly as below with retrieving. In my dev server it works

```
if (isset($username) && isset($password))
```

while in local wampserver it doesn't work? which extesnion or module i need this for.

I am now writing this for login page to work.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

then `if (isset($username) && isset($password))`

Now I cant change the code in whole project as everywhere they have not assigned the post variable.

Comment: You’d must be relying on the long outdated register_globals mechanism of PHP, and you must be using a rather old PHP version locally, if that still works. Using $_POST to access such parameters _is_ the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is [register_globals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

It had security risks and doesn't exist in any version of PHP which is still supported.

To get it you would need to go back to PHP 4.3 which reached [end of life](https://www.php.net/eol.php) 14 years, 7 months ago    .

Comment: Thanks for your help.. Yes it is the register_globals extension. I am using higher version of PHP so this extension was not available. How can I make the project run in local server? Do I need to use $_POST for each variable? Or there is any other way?

Comment: Use `$_POST`. There are hacks you could use, but they bring back all the security risks of register_globals so I can't, in good conscience, describe them.